# Using Python to extract EXIF tags added by Windows Photo Gallery 2012

Tags: python, jpeg, exif

I am trying to extract the "Descriptive tags" and "People tags" added to a .jpg image using Windows Photo Gallery 2012.

I an extracting the EXIF information using:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('temp.jpg')
exif_data = img._getexif()
print exif_data
```

But I don't understand what EXIF key corresponds to "Descriptive tag" and "People tag", and I can't work out how to convert the tags to human readable format.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports:

```
from PIL import ExifTags, Image
```

Then:

```
In [19]: img = Image.open('picture.jpg')

In [20]: img._getexif()
Out[20]: 
{271: u'Canon',
 272: u'Canon PowerShot S40',
 274: 1,
 282: (180, 1),
 283: (180, 1),
 296: 2,
 306: u'2003:12:14 12:01:44',
 531: 1,
 33434: (1, 500),
 33437: (49, 10),
 34665: 196,
 36864: '0220',
 36867: u'2003:12:14 12:01:44',
 36868: u'2003:12:14 12:01:44',
 37121: '\x01\x02\x03\x00',
 37122: (5, 1),
 37378: (149, 32),
 37381: (194698, 65536),
 37383: 2,
 37385: 24,
 37386: (682, 32),
 37500: '\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00(\x00\x00\x00D\x04\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x94\x04\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x9c\x04\x00\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xda\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xe6\x04\x00\x00\x06\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\xee\x04\x00\x00\x07\x00\x02\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x05\x00\x00\x08\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00;\xe1\x11\x00\t\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00&\x05\x00\x00\x10\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x01\r\x00\x03\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00F\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x05\x00\x01\x00\x030\x01\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xaa\x02\xe3\x00 \x00\x95\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff1\x00\xe0\x08\xe0\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\xaa\x02\x1e\x01\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x14\x01\x95\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x020\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x03\x00\x00\x95\x00!\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00IMG:PowerShot S40 JPEG\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Firmware Version 1.10\x00\x00\x00Andreas Huggel\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x03\x00\x01\x80z\x01\x01\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\x00\xc6\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 37510: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 40960: '0100',
 40961: 1,
 40962: 2272,
 40963: 1704,
 40965: 1416,
 41486: (2272000, 280),
 41487: (1704000, 210),
 41488: 2,
 41495: 2,
 41728: '\x03',
 41985: 0,
 41986: 0,
 41987: 0,
 41988: (2272, 2272),
 41990: 0}

In [21]: exif_human = { ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v for k, v in img._getexif().items() if k in ExifTags.TAGS}

In [22]: exif_human
Out[22]: 
{'ApertureValue': (149, 32),
 'ColorSpace': 1,
 'ComponentsConfiguration': '\x01\x02\x03\x00',
 'CompressedBitsPerPixel': (5, 1),
 'CustomRendered': 0,
 'DateTime': u'2003:12:14 12:01:44',
 'DateTimeDigitized': u'2003:12:14 12:01:44',
 'DateTimeOriginal': u'2003:12:14 12:01:44',
 'DigitalZoomRatio': (2272, 2272),
 'ExifImageHeight': 1704,
 'ExifImageWidth': 2272,
 'ExifInteroperabilityOffset': 1416,
 'ExifOffset': 196,
 'ExifVersion': '0220',
 'ExposureMode': 0,
 'ExposureTime': (1, 500),
 'FNumber': (49, 10),
 'FileSource': '\x03',
 'Flash': 24,
 'FlashPixVersion': '0100',
 'FocalLength': (682, 32),
 'FocalPlaneResolutionUnit': 2,
 'FocalPlaneXResolution': (2272000, 280),
 'FocalPlaneYResolution': (1704000, 210),
 'Make': u'Canon',
 'MakerNote': '\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00(\x00\x00\x00D\x04\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x94\x04\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x9c\x04\x00\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xda\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xe6\x04\x00\x00\x06\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\xee\x04\x00\x00\x07\x00\x02\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x05\x00\x00\x08\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00;\xe1\x11\x00\t\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00&\x05\x00\x00\x10\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x01\r\x00\x03\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00F\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x05\x00\x01\x00\x030\x01\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xaa\x02\xe3\x00 \x00\x95\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff1\x00\xe0\x08\xe0\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\xaa\x02\x1e\x01\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x14\x01\x95\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x020\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x03\x00\x00\x95\x00!\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00IMG:PowerShot S40 JPEG\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Firmware Version 1.10\x00\x00\x00Andreas Huggel\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x03\x00\x01\x80z\x01\x01\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\x00\xc6\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 'MaxApertureValue': (194698, 65536),
 'MeteringMode': 2,
 'Model': u'Canon PowerShot S40',
 'Orientation': 1,
 'ResolutionUnit': 2,
 'SceneCaptureType': 0,
 'SensingMethod': 2,
 'UserComment': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 'WhiteBalance': 0,
 'XResolution': (180, 1),
 'YCbCrPositioning': 1,
 'YResolution': (180, 1)}
```

**UPD**

The stuff you need is not EXIF, it is XMP metadata.
You can use http://python-xmp-toolkit.readthedocs.org, I created image with Windows PhotoGallery and add these tags that you described, and I found it using this library.

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't know which EXIF key corresponds to the 'People' and 'Description' tags. I placed the file under GIT revision control, so I know the content changes when a new tag is added. But I can't see the new tag in the EXIF data.

Comment: Thank you, a description of the XMP tags used by Photo Gallery is below: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pix/archive/2006/08/16/702780.aspx